# 3Ds Max: How do I extrude multiple faces at once?

Tags: 3d, polygon, modeling, 3dsmax

Beginner question, when I select a face, shift and select another face for extrusion the second section bounces back. I'm coming from using Blender so find Max confusing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hold Ctrl and select the faces you want to extrude. Ctrl allows multiple selections in 3ds max.